# XMLHttpRequest - Error "Bad Request - Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand"

Tags: apex, apexrest, website-integration

I am sending XMLHttpRequest using apex but unfortunately below Error is Coming

Error Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Here is my code.

```
public class A99AcresIntegration{

     public static void makeGetCallout(){
         String User_name = 'XXXXXXXX';
         String Pwd = 'XXXXXXXXX';
         DateTime Startdate = system.now()- 2;
         DateTime EndDate =   system.now();
         Http http = New Http();
         HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('http://www.99acres.com/99api/v1/getmy99Response/OeAuXClO43hwseaXEQ/uid/<?xml  version=1.0+?><query><user_name> '+User_name+'</user_name><pswd>'+Pwd+'</pswd><start_date>'+Startdate+'</start_date><end_date>'+EndDate+'</end_date></query>'); 

         request.setMethod('POST');
         request.setHeader('Content-Type','Text/xml');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);           
     }
}
```

Please give solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put body in body

```
public static void makeGetCallout(){
     String User_name = 'XXXXXXXX';
     String Pwd = 'XXXXXXXXX';
     DateTime Startdate = system.now()- 2;
     DateTime EndDate =   system.now();
     Http http = New Http();
     HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('http://www.99acres.com/99api/v1/getmy99Response/OeAuXClO43hwseaXEQ/uid/'); 
request.setBody('<?xml  version=1.0+?><query><user_name> '+User_name+'</user_name><pswd>'+Pwd+'</pswd><start_date>'+Startdate+'</start_date><end_date>'+EndDate+'</end_date></query>');

     request.setMethod('POST');
     request.setHeader('Content-Type','Text/xml');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);           
     }
```